# Deploying Telescope App to Amazon EC2

Tags: meteor, amazon-ec2, telescope

What am I doing wrong? I'm trying to deploy my Telescope app. I'm using this to do that: https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up. It gives me an error when I try to deploy using Mup. Here's my mup.json config file:

```
{
  // Server authentication info
  "servers": [
    {
      "host": "52.25.228.14",
      "username": "ec2-user",
      //"password": "password"
      // or pem file (ssh based authentication)
      "pem": "~/Documents/appname/appname.pem"
    }
  ],

  // Install MongoDB in the server, does not destroy local MongoDB on future setup
  "setupMongo": true,

  // WARNING: Node.js is required! Only skip if you already have Node.js installed on server.
  "setupNode": true,

  // WARNING: If nodeVersion omitted will setup 0.10.36 by default. Do not use v, only version number.
  "nodeVersion": "0.10.36",

  // Install PhantomJS in the server
  "setupPhantom": true,

  // Show a progress bar during the upload of the bundle to the server. 
  // Might cause an error in some rare cases if set to true, for instance in Shippable CI
  "enableUploadProgressBar": true,

  // Application name (No spaces)
  "appName": "appname",

  // Location of app (local directory)
  "app": "~/Documents/appname/Telescope",

  // Configure environment
  "env": {
    "ROOT_URL": "ec2-52-25-228-14.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com"
  },

  // Meteor Up checks if the app comes online just after the deployment
  // before mup checks that, it will wait for no. of seconds configured below
  "deployCheckWaitTime": 15
}
```

Comment: add http:// to the beginning of your ROOT_URLand see if that fixes the issue

Comment: Also what instance are you using, some of them require different usernames other than ec2-user

Answer (score 1):

Common pitfalls :

- Are sure you ran `mup setup` before deploying ?
- Try using a relative path to setup the app location, ie replace `~/Documents/appname/Telescope` by `.` if your `mup.json` is located at the root of your Telescope instance.

Answer (score 0):

I did run mup setup, did use http://, and tried many times to get it to connect/deploy.

I gave up and just went with a Wordpress theme and am customizing it how I want it. The other way was way too complicated. It didn't allow me to do what I wanted in a timely manner. Thanks for trying to help though guys.